# Are creating go routines asynchrnous?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm trying to fetch the content of an API with numerous goroutines.
I'm using a for loop to iterate over different character, but it seems like the forloop reaches its final value, before the requests are sent off.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

type people struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main(){

    names := make(chan string, 25)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 25; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            var p people
            url := fmt.Sprintf("https://swapi.dev/api/people/%d", i)
            getJSON(url, &p)
            names <- p.Name
        }()
    }
    name := <-names
    fmt.Println(name)
    wg.Wait()

}

func getJSON(url string, target interface{}) error {
    r, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
    return nil
}
```

Also, if somebody could improve my code quality, I'd be very grateful, I'm very new to Golang and don't have anybody to learn from!

Comment: What do you mean "seems like the forloop reaches its final value"? What are you expecting to happen, and how did that differ from what you observe? You receive the first value, print it, then wait for the rest of the goroutines to complete.

Comment: So I expected 25 different requests to be fired off, however, 25 requests were made of the same type. /api/25 was fired 25 times, instead of /api/1, /api/2, /api/3... etc

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: `i` is the same variable in each go routine, you need to use a new variable for each. I can write up a solution when I get home if no one else does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go routines are all using the same variable `i`. So on the first loop, you launch a goroutine that makes a url from `i`, and on the next loop `i` is incremented before that routine has a chance to run.

It's a common mistake in GoLang. The solution is to make a variable for each loop, and pass that one forward. You can either do it with a closure like this ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/glGPvm5fSdt)).

```
    for i := 0; i < 25; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        localI := i
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            var p people
            // Use LocalI here
            url := fmt.Sprintf("https://swapi.dev/api/people/%d", localI)
            getJSON(url, &p)
            names <- p.Name
        }()
    }
```

Or as an argument to the function (playground)

```
    for i := 0; i < 25; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        localI := i
        go func(localI int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            var p people
            // Use LocalI here
            url := fmt.Sprintf("https://swapi.dev/api/people/%d", localI)
            getJSON(url, &p)
            names <- p.Name
         // Pass i here. Since I is a primitive, it is passed by value, not reference.
         // Meaning a copy is made.
        }(i) 
    }
```

Here is a good writeup on the mistake you made:
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables

And the one above it is good to read too!